# SQL: SELECT TOP 2 DATES FOR EACH GROUP ID

Tags: sql, date, select, sql-server-2000

I have a table with entries like the following and i'm struggling with grouping when a date is involved.

```
  id    ref    startDate     
 ----  ----- -------------  
   1    001     01-01-2013       
   2    001     03-02-2013       
   3    002     31-01-2013       
   4    002     15-01-2013       
   5    001     05-06-2013 ....
```

What i'm trying to do is select the top 2 max dates for each ref so I get the following.

```
  id    ref    startDate     
 ----  ----- -------------  
   5    001     05-06-2013   
   2    001     03-02-2013       
   3    002     31-01-2013       
   4    002     15-01-2013
```

I think it meant to go along the lines of..

```
SELECT *
FROM   TABLE a
JOIN   (SELECT startDate
        FROM   TABLE b
        JOIN   TABLE c
        ON     b.ref = c.ref AND b.startDate >= c.startDate
        GROUP BY ref) AS d
ON     a.ref = b.ref
```

I using SQL 2000 so partition is out of the question unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Just place this clause (Modified to suit your needs) Somewhere in your query, it should give you only the top two StartDate's for a particular ref.

```
WHERE b.StartDate IN 

(SELECT TOP 2 StartDate FROM b WHERE a.ref = b.ref ORDER BY StartDate DESC)
```

As your `JOIN` appears to be what you tried to filter it with initially, replace the `JOIN` you have with the `WHERE` above. Make sure you edit it so it will match your actual table name

Comment: It should be `SELECT TOP 2 StartDate`

Comment: where about in the query does it need to be? do I need to remove some of the code I already have written?

Comment: As your `join` appears to be what you tried to filter it with initially, replace the `join` you have with the `where` above. Make sure you edit it so it will match your actual table name.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method using a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE t
WHERE (select count(*)
       from Table t2
       where t2.ref = t.ref and
             t2.date >= t.date
      ) <= 2;
```

This assumes that the dates are unique within each group.

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/39fb1/1) is a SQL Fiddle showing it working.

EDIT:

If the dates are not unique, then this can be modified to get the top rows for the top two dates this way:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE t
WHERE (select count(distinct t2.date)
       from Table t2
       where t2.ref = t.ref and
             t2.date >= t.date
      ) <= 2;
```

Or, it can be limited to exactly two rows this way:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE t
WHERE (select count(*)
       from Table t2
       where t2.ref = t.ref and
             (t2.date > t.date or t2.date = t.date and t2.id <= t.id)
      ) <= 2;
```

Comment: It's only bringing up 1 entry for most of the records even though there is around 5+ for them. The dates aren't duplicate either.

Comment: @Hazel . . . I might guess that your "dates" are really `datetime` values with a time on them.

Comment: they are datetime but all are 00:00:00.000.

Comment: @Hazel . . . Check out the SQL Fiddle.  The code in the answer does work.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this

```
DECLARE @REF_TABLE AS TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),REF VARCHAR(10))
DECLARE @LOOP_COUNT INT
DECLARE @ID INT=1
DECLARE @REF VARCHAR(10)
SELECT @LOOP_COUNT=COUNT(*) FROM @REF_TABLE
SELECT * INTO #TEMP FROM YOURTABLE WHERE 1=2
INSERT INTO @REF_TABLE SELECT DISTINCT REF FROM YOURTABLE
WHILE @LOOP_COUNT<@ID
BEGIN
SELECT @REF=REF FROM @REF_TABLE WHERE ID=@ID
INSERT INTO #TEMP SELECT TOP 2 * FROM YOURTABLE WHERE REF=@REF ORDER BY startDate DESC
SELECT @ID=@ID+1

END

SELECT * FROM #TEMP`
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this gives what you need (I understand it is bit long as we can't use CTE or any windows functions).

For testing purposes, I have added couple of extra records (`same ref with duplicate startdate` and `different refs with same startdate`), and commented.

**[Sql fiddle is here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b5040/1)**

```
select min(id) id, t.ref, t.sdate
from t join (
     select ref, max(sdate) as sdate
     from t
     group by ref

     union

     select t.ref, max(t.sdate) as sdate
     from t join (
         select ref, max(sdate) as sdate
         from t
         group by ref
     ) t2 on t.ref = t2.ref and t.sdate < t2.sdate
     group by t.ref 
  ) x on t.ref = x.ref and t.sdate = x.sdate
group by t.ref, t.sdate 
order by t.ref, t.sdate desc
```